# eval('document.all.txtname') is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

My name is Ashish Kumar. In my project i have used multiple controls(textbox, lable,checkbox) with same id. That works fine in ie but not Mozilla. For example.

```
function jsContentPageLoad() { 
var obj = eval('document.all.txtName');
alert('txt Lenght: ' + obj.length);
alert('txt1: ' + obj[0].value);
alert('txt2: ' + obj[1].value);
}


<input type="text" id = "txtName" name = "txtName" value ="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id = "txtName" name = "txtName"  value ="txt2"/>
```

And i don't want to use **"document.getElementbyName"** or **"document.getElementByClassName"**, because these takes more time compare to **eval('document.all.txtName')** and **"document.getElementbyID"**.

Now i don't want to make any big change to make compatible this project for mozilla, because this project is very big.and to replace document.all is easy but if i'll make id's to unique this will be big change for me. Because this project 10 years old and these is approx 350 pages in this project. And i have used document.all to make array of object. not get only single object. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Speed is very rarely an issue when you're using Javascript. I suggest you just use one of the methods you mentioned above, unless it really has a - noticable! - impact on performance. And of course you need to make your IDs unique. That's why they're IDs.

Comment: Use the standard functions. `document.all` is no longer supported in IE11: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your IDs are not unique - you need to fix that.

Second, `document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft extension, which is why it doesn't work in Firefox.

Finally, to answer your question, replace instances of `document.all` with `document.getElementById` instead:

```
<input type="text" id = "txtName1" name = "txtName" value ="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id = "txtName2" name = "txtName"  value ="txt2"/>

document.getElementById("txtName1");
document.getElementById("txtName2");
```

In fact you could even do a regex replace across your project to replace all instances of `document.all`, this would take no time at all.

Comment: But Dear problem is to replace document.all is easy but if i'll make id's to unique this will be big change for me. Because this project is 10 years old and these are approx 350 pages in this project. And i have used document.all to make array of object. not get only single object.

Comment: Those are your options. If you are upgrading, *do it right*, workarounds will just leave you in the same position a few years down the line. The new `document.querySelectorAll` method could be very useful for you. None of these calls are going to be slow enough to impact performance on your application.

Comment: Workarounds will always come back and haunt you sooner or later. It'd be in your best interest to do it properly.